# Double Pendulum Intuition

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, complex-systems

I have arrived at the equations of motion for a double pendulum, with gravity $g$, masses $m_i$, link lengths $l_i$, angles $\theta_i$, and applied torques $\tau_i$.
Please see the diagram and derivation at [Diego Assencio's blog](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=1500c66ae7ab27bb0106467c68feebc6).

I end up with a vector equation in matrix $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and $2 \times 1$ vector $b$.

$$A(\theta_1, \theta_2) \begin{bmatrix} \ddot{\theta_1} \\ \ddot{\theta_2} \end{bmatrix} + b(\theta_1, \theta_2, \dot{\theta_1}, \dot{\theta_2}) = \begin{bmatrix} \tau_1 \\ \tau_2 \end{bmatrix} $$
See [1] at the bottom of this post for the expanded form.

Solving, we can see how applying exogenous torqes influences the angular accelerations of the system.

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \ddot{\theta_1} \\ \ddot{\theta_2} \end{bmatrix} = A(\theta_1, \theta_2)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} \tau_1 \\ \tau_2 \end{bmatrix} - A(\theta_1, \theta_2)^{-1} b(\theta_1, \theta_2, \dot{\theta_1}, \dot{\theta_2})  $$

On account by multiplying through by $A^{-1}$, we see that an exogenous torque $\tau_2$ will contribute to both angular accelerations $\ddot{\theta_1}$ and $\ddot{\theta_2}$. This is what the mathematics tells us, but I can't wrap my head around what's physically happening. Supposing I had an actuator in the second joint and I apply torque, how does the first joint know it has to angular-ly accelerate?

[1] $$\ddot{\theta_1} l_{1}^{2} \left(m_{1} + m_{2}\right) + \ddot{\theta_2} l_{1} l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2} \right)} + \dot{\theta_2}^{2} l_{1} l_{2} m_{2} \sin{\left(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2} \right)} - \tau_{1} + g l_{1} \left(m_{1} + m_{2}\right) \sin{\left(\theta_{1} \right)} = 0$$
$$\ddot{\theta_1} l_{1} l_{2} m_{2} \cos{\left(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2} \right)} + \ddot{\theta_2} l_{2}^{2} m_{2} - \dot{\theta_1}^{2} l_{1} l_{2} m_{2} \sin{\left(\theta_{1} - \theta_{2} \right)} - \tau_{2} + g l_{2} m_{2} \sin{\left(\theta_{2} \right)} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

- `O <- origin, fixed`
- `| <- rod1`
- `● <- mass1`
- `| <- rod2`
- `● <- mass2`

Torque on mass2 will move rod2 which puts a torque on mass1 which moves rod1.